# Slides Scrolling Speed in the fullPage.js plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, fullpage.js

Settings FullPage.js plugin have option "scrollingSpeed". This value controls speed both elements - sections and slides. How can I set scrolling speed for slides and sections separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not by any of the fullpage.js options at least.

There's [an open topic in the fullpage.js github issues](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1068) since a long time ago.